# In Vuetify, how can I make a dynamically list with checkboxes clickable to select them?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuetify.js

I'm trying to create a dynamically generated list (with data from an API), then make the list items clickable to select these items.

The problem is that in this version, the checkboxes work properly, however the rows cannot be clicked to check them.

Template:

```
<div id="app">
  <v-app>
    <v-list dark>
      <v-list-tile v-for="(color) in colors" :key="color.hex" @click="">
        <v-list-tile-action>
          <v-checkbox v-model="selected" multiple :value="color" />
        </v-list-tile-action>
        <v-list-tile-content @click="">
          <v-list-tile-title>{{ color.label }}</v-list-tile-title>
        </v-list-tile-content>
      </v-list-tile>
    </v-list>
    <p>Selected items:</p>
    <pre>{{ selected }}</pre>
  </v-app>
</div>
```

JavaScript:

```
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: () => ({
    selected: [],
    colors: [
      { hex: "#f00", label: "Red" },
      { hex: "#0f0", label: "Green" },
      { hex: "#00f", label: "Blue" }
    ]
  })
});
```

Codepen to play around with it: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/vvqeLz

Compared to the given example, there's no fixed variable I can pre-create to mark a checkbox as selected, and I need the data in one array (as is correctly happening now) to process this later on. Note that the example is simplified to the bare-bone minimum. (excluding props and so forth)

Does anyone have a genius idea on how to make the list items clickable to check the boxes properly?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is my attempt at it, see the [Codepen example](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/LMKOGv)

What I did was create a method which toggles the adding and removing of a color in the array. Then I added the click functionality for the row itself with `@click.capture.stop="toggleColor(color)"`.

The `.capture.stop` part checks whether a user clicked on a select box first, and if so it stops the method from firing again. Else once you click a select box both the select box and the row toggle the value, thus cancelling each other out

```js
methods: {
  toggleColor (color) {
    if (this.selected.includes(color)) {
      // Removing the color
      this.selected.splice(this.selected.indexOf(color), 1);
    } else {
      // Adding the color
      this.selected.push(color);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: @HoffZ in your codepen link it only work when directly clicking the checkbox. OP wanted it to work when clicking somewhere on the entire list tile element which is why the method and `@click` handler was required

Answer (score 2):

[Codepen Link](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/MZMERv)

```
  computed: {
    selected: function() {
      return this.colors.filter(color => color.selected)
    }
  }
```

Brings you every selected colors as an Array.

This solution gives you 2 advantages over your one. You can predefine what should be checked before it even gets clicked once, and you can also easily implement a manipulation of the clicked value of the Array outside of the checkbox itself.

Comment: If you click on a select box it doesn't get added/removed immediately, you need to click twice

Comment: @T.Dirks Interesting Problem :o

Comment: Also, the pre-selected item isn't checked however present in the selected list (╯°□°）╯︵ ┻━┻

Comment: Code pen example looks great! Thanks

Answer (score 1):

[Codepen Link](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/OreOPM?editors=1010)

```
    processColorClick(color) {
      let idx = this.selected.indexOf(color);
      if (idx === -1) {
        this.selected.push(color);
      }
      else {
        this.selected.splice(idx, 1);
      }
    }
```

@Badgy, mutating of original data - is bad.
Method is better.

---

UPD: [one more solution](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/GPbOjp?editors=1010)

Comment: Also works but you don´t have the benefit of presetting the values (true|false)

Comment: mutating of data - is very bad practice.

Comment: Works perfectly and well, but I'm going with @t-dirsk answer as it's a bit more failsafe and complete. Still, thanks a lot for the help :D